# Isomorphism of $4$ dimensional hilbert space with tensor product of two dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I want to know what will be the isomorphic map between $\mathbb{C}^4$  over $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}^2\otimes \mathbb{C}^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$, as a $4$ dimensional Hilbert space they are isomorphic right?

Now my second question is bit motivated from Physcs (quantum information Theory, Entanglement states): [image: Last Two Line Of this screenshot]

I don't understand Last Two Line Of this screenshot. Could anyone help me to understand?

Comment: Yes the isomorphism $\mathbb{C}^{4}$ with $\mathbb{C}^{2} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}^{2}$ is correct. I think what the last two lines mean, translating into math, the composite system is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{4}$ the 4-dimensional state vectors that are tensor product of 2-dimensional state are the set of pure tensors (e.g. elements of the form $ u \otimes v$ , $u, v \in \mathbb{C}^{2}$). A rough analogy would be take taking a basis of $\mathbb{C}^{4}$ generated by $e_{i} \otimes e_{j}$  the sparse subset are only the lines along the basis vectors.

Comment: So does that Mean that all 4 dimensional vector can not be written as tensor products of two dimensional vectors?

Comment: If you're asking what I think you are, then the answer is yes. For example, $e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2$

Answer (score 2):

Let $e_1,e_2$ denote the standard (orthonormal) basis of $\Bbb C^2$.

The elements $\{e_i \otimes e_j\}$ for $i,j$ from $1$ to $2$ form a basis for $\Bbb C^2 \otimes \Bbb C^2$.  The most commonly used isomorphism (from $\Bbb C^2 \otimes \Bbb C^2$ to $\Bbb C^4$) is that associated with the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product); this isomorphism is given by
$$
e_1 \otimes e_1 \mapsto e_1\\
e_1 \otimes e_2 \mapsto e_2\\
e_2 \otimes e_1 \mapsto e_3\\
e_2 \otimes e_2 \mapsto e_4\\
$$
Presumably, they mean something very specific by a "sparse subset" (perhaps that the ratio of their measures is zero? Can't be sure here).  They clarify that what they *mean* by saying that the set of pure product states is sparse is that *most* states are entangled (i.e. not pure product states).